# Setup of crontab on OSX Running Java code

Tags: java, terminal, osx-snow-leopard, cron

I have a text file called cron.txt that is referencing a java call. findme.txt:

`java -classpath /example/...jkk/ findthesethings | mailx -s "does this work" email@address.com`

This is the one line that is in my cron.txt file:

`0 * * * * /Users/USERNAME/Desktop/scripts/findme.txt`

Then in terminal I type crontab cron.txt, this appears to setup cron to run etc as an output of crontab -l will show me the body of cron.txt... yet nothing appears to run on the hour?

Comment: I just ran a test and took my findme.txt and ran it manually in terminal. Perhaps part of the issue is that now that the java command appears to be done. (terminal is just sitting at a blank line) it hasn't moved onto the mailx phase. Is there something I need to do to say OK that java command is complete?

Comment: I'm now thinking that the above is a problem but also that cron isn't running, I can't find a log file here: /var/log/cron

Comment: looks like my cron log file is in usr/sbin/cron